# Error with App Engine split health checks

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I am unable to deploy my App Engine Flex Python project with split health checks.

I have enabled health checks:

```
$ gcloud beta app describe
...
featureSettings:
  splitHealthChecks: true
```

Using the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) as a model, my app.yaml has:

```
readiness_check:
  path: '/health_check'
  check_interval_sec: 5
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  app_start_timeout_sec: 600

liveness_check:
  path: '/health_check'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
```

But when I deploy, it fails due to the following error:

```
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 515, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 109, in init_process
    super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 122, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 130, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmruntime/wsgi.py", line 48, in <module>
    wsgi_config.get_module_config_filename())
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vmruntime/wsgi_config.py", line 48, in get_module_config
    return appinfo_includes.Parse(f)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 57, in Parse
    appyaml, _ = ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(appinfo_file, open_fn)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 82, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 2417, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 227, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 178, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
EventError: Unexpected attribute 'failure_threshold' for object of type ReadinessCheck.
```

I'm following the documentation so I'm not sure why it would be triggering an error here.

The only thing I can imagine is that my 'site-packages' is perhaps out of date? I don't believe my Docker should install any `google/appengine/` libraries, but I'm at a loss for what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have the latest SDK? Run `gcloud components update` and try again?

Comment: Yes, I had checked that first, and got no updates. :/

Comment: If you run `gcloud version` what version of `app-engine-python` is shown?

Comment: Looks like `app-engine-python` 1.9.64. Seems 1.9.65 was released a few days ago, but `gcloud components update` shows no updates still.

Comment: Oh, is this something that should be pulled in by the Docker image? I'm using the deprecated `gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat-multicore`, so perhaps this is fallout from that? Let me poke around a bit more, regenerate some images, and get back to you.

Comment: Rebuilt all my docker images (based off `python-compat-multicore`), and still seeing problems. Where are the updated appengine python files included from...`gcr.io/google_appengine/python`? If so, I guess that means I'd need to rebuild a version of `python-compat-multicore` for myself, to make this work?

Comment: Probably should post your entire `app.yaml` in your question. There are a few other settings that might be at play here.

Comment: Full app.yaml: https://github.com/mikelambert/dancedeets-monorepo/blob/master/server/app.yaml (only difference, being that these healthcheck lines are commented-out in this linked version, so that my push will work)

Comment: Hey @brettj, The python-compat-runtime has a git commit 23 Jul 2017, but the docker image was never rebuilt to include it, and is the source of my problems. Is it possible to rebuild the deprecated runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So seems the above failure scenario is caused by the  `gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat-multicore` docker image being out of date.

The [github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-compat-runtime/) is up to date with the latest python files, but the associated Docker image was never rebuilt.

I have fixed this particular error by checking out the github and rebuilding the docker image myself, and pointing my appengine flex stuff at my own parent-built-image.

(I now have a separate problem, with split healthchecks being sent to the default paths, and it not letting me override the paths. I have filed that as bug in the Google cloud issue tracker. But at least the above question is now solved for me)

Comment: This worked! I can't tell you how many hours I wasted going down rabbit holes here. Amazing, thank you! To get this working for me, I also had to set the undocumented `host` field in my health checks, e.g., `host: mysite.com`